# Jquery: display parent in textarea even if only one child selected

Tags: jquery, select, checkbox, parent-child

I have checkbox list and if child is selected the parent is selected automatically, then all selections are displayed in textarea.

The problem:

When only one child is selected, Parent is not displayed in textarea. It is displayed when more then 1 child is selected. I need that parent will be displayed on textarea even if only one child is selected

code: http://jsfiddle.net/NVhnw/

Html:

```
            <ul class="taglist">
            <li class="category">Category:
                <ul>                
                    <li class="category"><input type="checkbox" name="A" value="Parent">Parent
                           <ul>     
                                <li><input type="checkbox" class="liChild" name="A" value="Child1">Child1</li>      
                                <li><input type="checkbox" class="liChild" name="A" value="Child2">Child2</li>      
                            </ul>
                    </li>   
                </ul>   
            </ul>          
            <br/>
            You checked:
            <br/>
            <textarea rows="4" cols="50" class="textfield"  name="describe" class="required" id="describe">
            </textarea>
```

Jquery:

```
                //* Parent select if children selected*//

                $(document).ready(function() {
                $('input.liChild').change(function() {
                    $(this).closest('ul')
                           .siblings('input:checkbox')
                           .prop('checked', $(this).closest('ul')
                                                   .children()
                                                   .children('input:checkbox')
                                                   .is(':checked'))
                           .first().change();
                });


                $('li.category').addClass('plusimageapply');
                $('li.category').children().addClass('selectedimage');
                $('li.category').children().hide();
                $('li.category').each(
                function(column) {
                $(this).click(function(event){
                if (this == event.target) {
                if($(this).is('.plusimageapply')) {
                $(this).children().show();
                $(this).removeClass('plusimageapply');
                $(this).addClass('minusimageapply');
                }
                else
                {
                $(this).children().hide();
                $(this).removeClass('minusimageapply');
                $(this).addClass('plusimageapply');
                }
                }
                });
                }
                );
                });

                //*Text area update*//
                function updateTextArea() {     
                   var allVals = [];
                   $('.taglist :checked').each(function(i) {

                       allVals.push((i!=0?"\r\n":"")+ $(this).val());
                   });
                   $('#describe').val(allVals).attr('rows',allVals.length) ;

                   }
                   $(function() {
                      $('.taglist input').click(updateTextArea);
                      updateTextArea();
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
$('input.liChild').change(function() {
```

to

```
$('input.liChild').click(function() {
```

That worked for me on your fiddle